# Any way to use another objects position to control a gradient or falloff on an objects material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

GOAL: The idea is to use another objects position to create a gradient on my current object to kind of mimic a lights influence in a cycles material. 
I have used this kind of thing in 3dsmax using a falloff material which can take another objects position to generate a falloff towards the position of that object. Very handy to use as a mask to drop in different materials into highlight or shadow areas. 
I cannot do this with ordinary lighting because I want to use an emissive material strong on the lit side but faded on the dark side.
Any other solutions would be wonderful.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79851/make-an-objects-visibility-controlled-by-another-object-or-an-empty/

Comment: Answers in [this kind of area](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90023/how-can-i-feed-the-output-of-the-dynamic-paint-into-the-input-of-the-wireframe-n) might be useful, too..

Comment: Are you able to add an example image of what you're trying to achieve?